# Как извлечь кириллический текст из PDF файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, кириллица

Требуется извлечь весь текст из [данного](https://yadi.sk/i/1YnU6mp7q93nmw) PDF файла.
Использую следующий код:

```
import PyPDF4
pdf_file = open('1.pdf', 'rb')
read_pdf = PyPDF4.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
page = []
for i in range(0,number_of_pages):
    page.append('')

page_content = ''
for i in range(0,number_of_pages):
    page[i] = read_pdf.getPage(i)
    page_content = page_content+page[i].extractText()

file = open("file.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
file.write(page_content)
file.close()
```

> Автор данного кода @Assur

Проблема в том, что библиотека не читает кириллические символы (Пробовал извлечь текст из англоязычного файла, там всё прошло как нужно).

Comment: Попробуйте другие кодировки (koi-8r, cp1251 etc.)

Answer (score 0):

С не аски символами в пдф проблема в том что они часто вносятся через аккумулятор глифов - просто висящие в воздухе очертания букв без текста. Всё конечно зависит от генератора pdf, но часто текста там нет - только очертания.

Answer (score -1):

```
# miner_text_generator.py

import io

from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage

def extract_text_by_page(pdf_path):
    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as fh:
         for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh, 
                                  caching=True,
                                  check_extractable=True):
            resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
            fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
            converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle)
            page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)
            page_interpreter.process_page(page)

            text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()
            yield text

            # close open handles
            converter.close()
            fake_file_handle.close()

def extract_text(pdf_path):
    for page in extract_text_by_page(pdf_path):
        print(page)
        print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
     print(extract_text('w9.pdf'))
```

[Взято от сюда](https://python-scripts.com/exporting-data-from-pdf)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/433025)

Comment: Да конечно)....